# Difference between character and string when constructing a 1-d array of the specified type

Tags: julia

I am confusing with when constructing a 1-d array of the specified type by usung `getindex(type[, elements...])`.

Of course, that I can convert **Int 8** when the element are **Int**

```
getindex(Int8, 1, 2)

2-element Vector{Int8}:
1
2
```

Even when the element are **character** format, I can convert it to **Int8** :

```
getindex(Int8, '1', '2')

2-element Vector{Int8}:
49
50
```

However, I can not convert when the element are in *string* format.

```
getindex(Int8, "1", "2")
```

and, raise the following error :

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int8
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::Ptr) where T<:Integer at pointer.jl:23
  convert(::Type{IT}, ::GeometryBasics.OffsetInteger) where IT<:Integer at C:\Users\Admin\.julia\packages\GeometryBasics\WMp6v\src\offsetintegers.jl:40
  convert(::Type{T}, ::SentinelArrays.ChainedVectorIndex) where T<:Union{Signed, Unsigned} at C:\Users\CARVI\.julia\packages\SentinelArrays\tV9lH\src\chainedvector.jl:209
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(A::Vector{Int8}, x::String, i1::Int64)
   @ Base .\array.jl:839
 [2] getindex(#unused#::Type{Int8}, x::String, y::String)
   @ Base .\array.jl:393
 [3] top-level scope
   @ In[35]:1
 [4] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [5] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1116
```

Why `getindex()` allow **character** element to convert to different format (like character -> Int8), but **string** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, that's a rather weird way of writing array literals: `getindex(T, xs...)` is usually written as `T[xs...]`.

However, the error already quite clearly tells you what went wrong:

> Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int8

How do you imagine a general conversion from `String` to `Int8` to look like?  What 8-bit integer should correspond to the string `"slkdfjls"`, for example?  A string is after all a pretty much arbitrary sequence of bytes.  And contrary to your expectation, Julia does *not* make an attempt to do any parsing of the contained value (for that, use `parse(Int8, "1")`.

Characters on the other hand represent (if valid) single UTF-8 code points, and it is meaningful to reinterpret their fixed amount of bytes as a number:

```
julia> convert(Int16, '†')
8224

julia> convert(Int8, '1')  # certainly not Int8(1)!
49
```

The conversion is already borderline meaningful when the value exceeds the range of the target type:

```
julia> convert(Int8, '†')
ERROR: InexactError: trunc(Int8, 8224)
...
```

UTF-8 characters that happen to be representable by only one byte can be losslessly converted to `Int8`; this covers all of ASCII.  Above that, an error is raised.  This is no different from `convert(Int8, Int32(something))`.